# Redirect a large number of 404 pages

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a large number of 404's due to a site structure design change that need redirecting.

Can someone tell me how I can do this with a pattern in htaccess

```
key-creative-wedding-photography/60-the-key-to-creative-wedding-photography-3/contact
key-creative-wedding-photography/090-the-key-to-creative-wedding-photography-3/contact
hayling-island-beach/img_7459-hayling-island-beach/contact
farbridge-wedding-photographers/_0287-farbridge-wedding-photographers-2/contact
```

Please note there is a page called ./contact

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (preferably before any other rules that you have in that file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact$ /contact [L,R=301]
```

That takes anything that ends with `/contact`, with at least a folder before it, and redirects it to `/contact`.